# Could not load file or assembly 'GMap.NET.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, reference, wcf-data-services

I have a wcf Service application in VS2010.My local machine is a 32 bit OS where as the server is a 64 bit. There are around 6 services in my solution.
Im successfully able to host the application on IIS on my local machine.And it works fine.
But when i try host that service application on Server i gets the below error

**Could not load file or assembly 'GMap.NET.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**
I do have reference added in my solution for **GMap.NET.Core** .

**I have tried** to set the properties in my solution to **Any CPU** . Also in the application pool i have set the Enable 32-Bit Application to **True**. i have also set the Copy Local to **TRUE** in my solution before publishing.
When i run the source on through my solution i dont get any error and the solution is built successfully.

What else can i try to get my services successfully hosted on the Server and should be accessed through my application.
[image: Error due to GMap.NET.Core]

Answer (score 2):

This is caused 99% of the time due to 64bit/32bit. Perhaps your library is 32 bit only, but your project is compiling to 64 bit?

Comment: @shimoon yes.so what the solution to this?

Comment: @SamM Check that your project is compiling to the same as the library.